# Git Database - Everyone Pushing to Same Branch in Different Files

Tags: sql-server, git, visual-studio

Database team is implementing code changes, using Visual Studio SSDT database projects with Git source control. Everyone is pushing to main Release branch with code review (only 5 developers on the team). All the database coworkers are only allowed pushing to different files only (tables, sprocs, functions), etc. The way work is assigned, none of us push or work the same sql file. Eventually all good changes from Release (currently in Work) are merged into Master branch (Production Ready).

Code Review ---> Push to Release Branch (Currently in work during Sprint) ---> Merge to Master Production Ready Branch

(a) What are the negative consequences of utilizing this strategy in Git?

(b) For cleaner history, should everyone Rebase ReleasePublic Remote into ReleaseLocal, or conducting Pull? (Fetch/Merge), I would think Rebase is answer for cleaner history.

Note: I agree, it would be annoying only if we are working on the same file and pushing changes. Alternative Strategy to create different feature branches and then merge into main branch. We are refraining from this strategy since each developer has 10 dba admin related changes a day, creating many branches and merges is time consuming and cumbersome-

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow

[Devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4633/git-everyone-pushing-to-same-branch-in-different-files)

Comment: I'd summarise benefits of feature branches with 1. Cleaner main/release branch 2. Pull requests - please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is if it's working for you then it's working.

The purpose of the source control solution is to assist you in producing software.

Use this setup until it doesn't work and then adjust. (Please note that all 5 of the devs could start using feature branches, if they want/need, without interfering with the other team member's flow).

Having said that there are consequences of using a single branch. Here are two examples

---

### Releasable main/release branch

One of them could be shown in a following scenario:

1. A release happens
2. A commit with a bug in file A is committed
3. A commit file B is committed
4. You want to release the changes made to file B\
5. Now you don't have a releasable snapshot of the repo

If the changes for file A were tested in a feature branch then master/release branch is in a releasable state more often.

---

### Pull requests

Having feature branches allows to use Pull Requests (which is a layer on top of `git`) better - your code reviews may be get easier to enforce and track.

Comment: are there any negative consequences in Git? bad history, harder to see changes? we have not noticed anyhting

Comment: I added a consequence.

Comment: Re: 10 feature branches. A) If a dev creates 10 feature branches a day, but produces good solutions in the end, that's fine  B) if these 10 branches don't make sense and their code in them is bad then isolating these may have some benefits.

Comment: It sounds like you have it under control.